# Selecting multiple tables from database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to make my php code to read off of two tables in my database. Like if it does not exist in one table it will check the other and see.

```
$mystyle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images WHERE `name` = '$name'");
```

How would I make it read from the table images and the table images_2

I tried doing this: [but didn't work of course]

```
$mystyle = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM images, images_2 WHERE `name` = '$name'");
```

Comment: **Warning:** Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Also, `mysql_*` functions are deprecated and are soon to be removed. Switch to MySQLi or PDO and start using prepared statements :)

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: See http://bobby-tables.com/php and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/

Answer (score 5):

Use `UNION`(implicit distinct) or `UNION ALL` :

```
SELECT * FROM images WHERE `name` = '$name'
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM images_2 WHERE `name` = '$name'
```

Assuming `images` and `images_2` has the same table structure, otherwise you have to list the columns' names explicitly instead of `SELECT *`.

---

**Note that:** Use [**PDO**](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of `Mysql_*` functions, it is deprecated and vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: Looks like Ive got alot more coding to learn :L Could you give me an example of my code ^ in PDO or Mysqli?

Comment: @user2594383 - There is a lot of tutorials in the web, see [**this**](http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html), and [**this**](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will have to return a count of the rows from the `SELECT` on images and if zero then run the `SELECT` against images_2

Answer (score 0):

You can use UNION  ,

```
(SELECT 1 AS sort_col, col1a, col1b, ... FROM t1)
 UNION
(SELECT 2, col2a, col2b, ... FROM t2) ORDER BY sort_col;
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html